# Return name of list inside loop that's looping through list of lists

Tags: r, list, loops

I have two lists.

```
list1 <- list('a', 5, 9)
list2 <- list('q', 42, 51)
```

They are inside a larger named list.

```
metalist <- list()
metalist[['bob']] <- list1
metalist[['carol']] <- list2
```

How can I return the names of  each list from inside a loop?  I want to return `'bob'` and then `'carol'`.  The following code does not work because it looks for the names inside `list1` and `list2`, not the name that `list1` is given in `metalist`.

```
for(list in metalist) {
  print(names(list))
}
```

Comment: `list1` and `list2` are constructed as `vector`s.  Did you meant `list1 <- list('a', 5, 9)` and `list2 <- list('q', 42, 51)`. You need just `names(metalist)`

Comment: Yes, thanks I edited the question.

Comment: Why not iterate over the list names instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We loop through the `names` of the `list` and `print` it

```
for(nm in names(metalist)) print(nm)
#[1] "bob"
#[1] "carol"
```

Note that

```
names(metalist)
```

would give the `names` of each `list` element in the 'metalist'

---

Reason the OP's method is giving `NULL` is because when we extract the `list` element to its components

```
metalist[[1]]
#[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#[[2]]
#[1] 5

#[[3]]
#[1] 9
```

However, if it is not extracted fully. i.e. if it is still a `list` object with one element

```
metalist[1]
#$bob
#$bob[[1]]
#[1] "a"

#$bob[[2]]
#[1] 5

#$bob[[3]]
#[1] 9

names(metalist[1])
#[1] "bob"
```

In other words, the `names` attribute is just a layer outside the `list`.  So, we can't extract from inside unless it is looped through the `names`.

WHen looped through the `names` the components can be extracted with `[[`

```
for(nm in names(metalist)) print(metalist[[nm]])
```

Convenient option to deal with `list` are apply family functions (`lapply/sapply/..`)

```
lapply(names(metalist), function(nm) metalist[[nm]])
```